# Restrict Scope of LESS Css Variables

Tags: css, visual-studio, less, web-essentials

I use LESS Css with Web Essentials and Visual Studio.

I'm trying to create a form of inheritance whereas only specific variables can be seen across the project. For instance:

I have a file: `PublicVar.less`

PublicVar contains variables that I want to use across the project. To do so I simple add an `@import "PublicVar"` statement to each Less file that needs to use the variables inside.

However, PublicVar itself relies on helper variables, so for instance:

In PublicVar.less

```
@import "BreakpointVar";
@maxWidth: @bp1;
```

In BreakpointVar.less

```
@bp1: 1024px;
```

The reason they are separated out is for brevity.

However, with the above scenario, whenever I import PublicVar, intellisense also shows me all other supporting variables - @bp1 etc - so I get stacks of irrelevant variables to pick from.

If I wrap the import statement inside a mixin, the underlying variables are not bubbled up but intellisense shows a syntax error. **It will still compile though**.

```
.ImportBreakpoint() {
  @import "BreakpointVar";
}
.ImportBreakpoint();

    @maxWidth:@bp1
```

@bp1 is not picked up by intellisense - green squiggle (undeclared variable).

Out of the two scenarios, the last is better given that it masks all "internal" variables that shouldn't be seen, However, I wonder if there is a better way of achieving this hierarchy without breaking intellisense.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid currently this is impossible. I.e. you can't make a higher level scope variable to relay on a lower level scope variable. In your above mixin example `@bp1` is still in the same global scope and it's not shown by intellisense only because of its very poor Less support (it's very limited to understand most of Less syntax excluding the simplest things only). 
So if the trick works for you - it's fine I guess (not counting it looks a bit burdening and may lead to a problems when you'll need to override such variable) - at least I can't invent anything better at quick glance.

Answer (score 0):

In your PublicVar.less can try try to import your helper by importing as a reference :

```
@import (reference) "BreakpointVar";
```

[Doc about reference](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference)